# Error - Unexpected } at the end of While Loop

Tags: while-loop, autohotkey

I'm using while true loop to constantly check run this script. After adding the if expression with whitelist ahk gives an error about unexpected } at the end of code. As far as I know there should be }.

Using Loop command gives the same error.
Removing the problematic } at the end causes the code running in background but not doing anything.

```
;Setup
Sleep, 1000
whiteList = "none"

;Main Loop
While True
{
    siteName = YouTube
    WinGetActiveTitle, tabName
    Sleep, 10000

    if tabName = %whiteList%{
        Continue
    }

    ;If current website is Youtube, ask if am I supposted to be here
    if InStr(tabName, siteName){
        Sleep, 10000
        MsgBox, 292, Reality Check, Should you do this?
        IfMsgBox, Yes
        {
            whiteList = tabName
        }

        ;Close tab in mozilla
        else
        {   
            WinActivate, %tabName%
            Sleep, 10
            Send ^w
        }
    }   
}
```

Code is unfinished, It should run in background and when the user is using YouTube fore some time it should ask him whether is he supposted to watch Youtube.

If he clicks yes, the program should ignore that specific page.
Else it should close it.

Comment: I would recommend trying it with the `{` below the if-statement to see if that helps. Or, perhaps, add a space before the `{` so that there is at least one space between it and whatever else is next to it. You can also just do `Loop` with no parameters instead of `While True`, not that that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` around the whiteList-var shouldn't be there. When I wrote it like below it seems to work:

```
if tabName = whiteList
    Continue
```

Also the `whiteList = tabName` will just assign the string "tabName" to whiteList. Use `whiteList := tabName` for assigning, and `if var1 = var2` for comparison.

Comment: It also worked with the `{` and `}`, but since it's only one line they are not needed.